# javascript - show & hide

Tags: hide, show

I'm trying to create a show & hide toggle with the elements hidden when the page loads.
so far...

```css
.incl {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 800;
 background-color: #00689C;
 text-align: left;
 padding:0 5px 5px 5px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size:1em;
 border-radius:3px;
 line-height:1.4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   $("#incl").toggle(1000);
  });
 });
</script>

<button>INCLUDES</button>
  <div id="incl">
    <ul class="incl">
      <li>bla bla</li>
      <li>bla ti bla</li>
      <li>bla bla bla</li>
 </ul>
  </div>
```

The problem here is the content loads as I get to the page. I need it the other way around.

Comment: add `.incl { display: none; }`

Comment: Also, with this, I'de like the "includes" button change to say "hide"

Comment: `$("button").click(function(){ ... $(this).hide(); });`

Comment: then `#incl { display: none; }` insted of `.incl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `#incl { display: none; }` and `$("button").click(function(){ ... $(this).hide(); });`

```css
#incl {
     display: none;
 }

.incl {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 800;
 background-color: #00689C;
 text-align: left;
 padding:0 5px 5px 5px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size:1em;
 border-radius:3px;
 line-height:1.4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#incl").toggle(1000);
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<button>INCLUDES</button>
<div id="incl">
    <ul class="incl">
        <li>bla bla</li>
        <li>bla ti bla</li>
        <li>bla bla bla</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for that. I typed it wrong, I had it with the class selector not the ID selector. That's sorted.

Comment: `$("button").text('new text');` will change text in button, but you need to handle animation

Comment: thank you for all the help. this code I'm using is causing my button to disappear.                                                            $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){ 
     $("#incl").toggle(500);
     $(this).hide();
     $("button").text('hide');
     });
    });

Comment: `$(this).hide();` do the disappearing

Comment: you need to decide when you want to change text, if before the animation start or at some point when animation happening or after animation is complete, and handle clicking when animation isnt done yet, what is condition to show text 'hide' and 'INCLUDE' if its visibility of `#incl` or extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

add 
    #incl{display:none;} 
to css

Comment: What should happen, Will?

Comment: $(this).hide(); hides the button, I'de like to change the text in the button. to echo "hide"